# Reversing a Sentence without reversing Characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reverse

how do i reverse a sentence like "Hello World" to "World Hello" Not dlroW oleo
Been search for an example on this forum the whole day

```
function jump(str){
    var holder ="";
    var len = str.length-1;
    for(var i =len; i >= 0; i--){
        holder += str[i] ;
    }
    return holder.trim();
}
console.log(jump("Just do it!"))
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: `s.split(/ /).reverse().join(" ")`

Comment: What do you want to do with punctuation in the sentence? E.g., what result would you expect from "Hello, world!"? And do you want Java or Javascript (why tag your question with both)?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch this is what i have done so far...above

Comment: Java was a mistake @nnnnnn corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript there is a really easy way to do this:

```
var str = "Hello World";
str = str.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
console.log(str); // => "World Hello"
```

Basically, you split the string into an array using a space character as a delimiter so we can get an array of each word, then reverse that array and join them back into a string with the spaces we removed earlier.

Comment: Omg it worked but i tried this earlier but it didn't work. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Dragonstone Glad I could help! I suspect earlier you might not have been assigning the reversed string back to itself or something small like that.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned which language you are using, I will give you just steps
Steps:

1. Split by space, and store in an array or list
2. Reverse the order
3. Print by looping through the list